# How should 而 be understood in the "为了大好前程而赏赐"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following sentence is from a song lyric by AccuseFive. I don't think more context is needed for this question

> 常常处于被告知是为了大好前程而赏赐

I can see two ways of understanding 而 in this clause, and I'm sure one is obviously wrong from a natives perspective:

1. I'm often told it's a reward for a good future.
2. I'm often told it's for a good future and reward.

That is, in (1) 而 is understood as a kind of causal link, while in (2) it is understood as plainly as "and".

Answer (score 1):

Here, 而 is a conjunction between two phrases. The leading phase is the goal/cause, and the following phase is a logical action that enables one to achieve/satisfy the goal/cause. For example:

- "为了**大好前程**而**努力**" - "Try hard for (the sake of) a better future." The leading phase is "大好前程" (the goal/cause), and the following phase is "努力", which is a logical action that enables achieving the goal.

Similarly,

- "为了**大好前程**而**不顧一切**" - "Crass and hotheaded for (the sake of) a better future."

From the examples above, it should be clear that the lyric "为了大好前程而赏赐" does not make sense, as "赏赐(largess/reward)" is not a logical action that enables the achieving of the goal. However, it would make sense if modified as:

- 为了大好前程而**放棄**赏赐, which implies "for the sake of a better (political) future, rather give up the (option of) largess/reward. And the translation is,
- "Giving up the largess/reward exchange for a better (political) future."

Answer (score 0):

In this case 而 is a grammatical particle, making 前程 describe 賞賜.

Therefore, your first choice would be a more proper translation, but it is not a causal definition of 而, and the sentence literally can be understood as ".... in order for (myself to have) a very good future reward." future here is specifically future conditions/prospects.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 而 = and, but I agree with r13 "it should be clear that the lyric "为了大好前程而赏赐" does not make sense," but it is a pop song and not a definitve treatise on logic!

She met someone she likes and is not sure what to do??

珍惜突然成了一件没有大不了的事
Love suddenly doesn't seem so bad.
时光流逝
Time passes.
只怕满腹情怀会太像个孩子
(I'm) Just worried that, full of emotion, I will seem like a child,
常常处于被告知
Often I'm in the situation where I'm being told,
是为了大好前程而赏赐
it's for a better future and reward .(What is "it"??)
世道险恶的用心之至
(People's) Morals and extremely dangerous motives;
该怎么判断怎么知
How should I judge, how can I know?
丑人多作怪 我只能一刀往心里窜
Many shameless people behave badly, I can only flee with a dagger to the heart.
发现了你我都还迁就于情感
Discovering you and I both (are) both adapting to (our) feelings,
而不敢去想未来
and dare not contemplate the future.

Comment: I understand the point about pop songs not always making sense, which is why I never ask about what the lyrics "mean" on a deeper level. But in the vast majority of the songs in the languages I do know well (English and Swedish), almost every phrase does make *grammatical* sense that a native would have zero trouble understanding. The 而 has grammatically been interpreted differently so far in this thread, I will leave this open for some time more.